# Getting no database selected message. PHP,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database at local server. I am trying to access this database. I have table of venueTypeMaster in the database. I tried to get all the venuetypes from database. But when I run the script message I get is - 'No database selected'.

I have a class in which I have created two functions in php script. For createVenue it dose not send any message and the query has been executed successfully. But for getVeunueTypes it is showing this message. Connection for both is same.

DB Script:

```
    <?php
include_once("config.php");
include_once("exceptions.php");
class DB {
    static $con;

    public static function getConnection() {
        try {
            if ( DB::$con == null ) {
                DB::$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
                if ( DB::$con) {
                    $status  = mysqli_select_db(DB::$con,DB_NAME);
                    if (! $status )  throw new DBSelectionExcpetion(mysqli_error());
                    return DB::$con;
                } else {
                    $e = new DBConnectionException(mysqli_error());
                    throw $e;
                }
            }
            return DB::$con;
        } catch(DBConnectionException $e) {
            throw $e;
        } catch(DBSelectionExcpetion $de) {
            throw $de;
        }
        return null;
    }
?>
```

venueTypes script

```
    <?php
include("exceptions.php");
include("DB.php");
include("config.php");

class VenueTypes {

    public function getVenueTypes() {
        try {
            $con = DB::getConnection();

            $query = "select * from venueTypeMaster";

            $rs = mysql_query($query) or die (json_encode(array("result"=>-1, "message"=>mysql_error())));
            $n = mysql_num_rows($rs);

            $vt = array();

            if ( $n > 0 ) {

                while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                    $vt[] = $row;
                }

                $result = array("result"=>1, "message"=>"success", "venueTypes" => $vt);
                return json_encode($result);
            } else {
                $result = array("result"=>-1, "message"=>"Venue types list is empty");
                return json_encode($result);
            }
        } catch(DBConnectionException $e) {
            $result = array("result"=>-1, "message"=> $e -> getMessage());
            return json_encode($result);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function createVenueType($fields) {

        try {

            $required = array("venuetype", "active", "entry_by", "entry_date", "entry_time", "last_modify_date", "ip_addr","venue_name");
            $actual = array_keys($fields);
            $intersection = array_intersect($required, $actual);

            $n1 = sizeof($required);
            $n2 = sizeof($intersection);

            if ( $n1 != $n2 ) {
                throw new MissingParameterException();
            }
            $con = DB::getConnection();

            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = array_values($fields);

            $columns = implode(",", $keys);

            $n = sizeof($values);
            for($i=0;$i<$n; $i++) {
                $values[$i] = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$values[$i]) . "'";
            }

            $columnValues = implode(",", $values);

            $query = "insert into venuetypemaster($columns) values($columnValues)";

            mysqli_query($con,$query) or die (json_encode(array("result"=>-1, "message"=>mysqli_error())));
            $af = mysqli_affected_rows($con);
            if ( $af == 1 ) {
                $venuetypeId = mysqli_insert_id($con);
                $result = array("result"=>1, "message"=>"success", "venuetypeId" => $venuetypeId);
                return json_encode($result);
            } else {
                $result = array("result"=>-1, "message"=>"Failed to register");
                return json_encode($result);
            }
        } catch(DBConnectionException $e) {
            $result = array("result"=>-1, "message"=> $e -> getMessage());
            return json_encode($result);
        }
        return null;
    }
?>
```

getVenueType script

```
    <?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {

    include_once ("../include/VenueTypes.php");


    try {

            $v = new VenueTypes();
            $response = $v -> getVenueTypes();

            //$response is null means something went wrong as a result we got null result from above statement

            if ( $response == null ) {
                $response = json_encode(array("result" => -2, "message" => "Empty result"));
                echo $response;
            } else {
                echo $response;
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $result = array("result" => -1, "message" => $e -> getMessage());
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
    } else {
        $result = array("result" => -3, "message" => "Unsupported method : " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    ?>
```

Can anyone help please.. Thank you..

Comment: there is, what looks like, a typo `DBSelectionExcpetion` in `if (! $status )  throw new DBSelectionExcpetion(mysqli_error());`

Comment: sorry dint get you. @RamRaider

Comment: I'm not saying this is the cause of the problem but it might be - you have misspelled exception in `DBSelectionExcpetion` ~ if it is spelled incorrectly everywhere then no problems

Comment: Mysqli can take a DB name in the connect function. Is there any particular reason why you're not using `DB::$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing between the `mysqli_xxx()` and `mysql_xxx()` functions. These two libraries are not compatible with each other; you must only use one or the other throughout your code.

Since the `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete and deprecated, that means you should only use `mysqli_xxx()`.

1. Change all occurrences of `mysql_` in your code to `mysqli_`.
2. You will also need to make other changes to these lines of code -- notably this will include adding the DB reference variable (ie the variable returned by `getConnection()`), but some other syntax changes may also be necessary.